# Metadata version mismatch issue, When use Angular 8 library with Angular 4 App

Tags: angular

Error: Metadata version mismatch for module C:/Ravi/Angular/demo/Ang4/node_modules/mylibrary/mylibrary.d.ts, found version 4, expected 3, resolving symbol AppModule in C:/Ravi/Angular/demo/Ang4/src/app/app.module.ts, resolving symbol AppModule in C:/Ravi/Angular/demo/Ang4/src/app/app.module.ts
    at syntaxError (C:\Ravi\Angular\demo\Ang4\node_modules@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:1729:34)
    at simplifyInContext (C:\Ravi\Angular\demo\Ang4\node_modules@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:24979:23)
    at StaticReflector.simplify (C:\Ravi\Angular\demo\Ang4\node_modules@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:24991:13)
    at StaticReflector.annotations (C:\Ravi\Angular\demo\Ang4\node_modules@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:24418:41)
    at _getNgModuleMetadata (C:\Ravi\Angular\demo\Ang4\node_modules@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_impl.js:138:31)
    at _extractLazyRoutesFromStaticModule (C:\Ravi\Angular\demo\Ang4\node_modules@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_impl.js:109:26)
    at Object.listLazyRoutesOfModule (C:\Ravi\Angular\demo\Ang4\node_modules@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_impl.js:53:22)
    at Function.NgTools_InternalApi_NG_2.listLazyRoutes (C:\Ravi\Angular\demo\Ang4\node_modules@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_api.js:91:39)
    at AotPlugin._getLazyRoutesFromNgtools (C:\Ravi\Angular\demo\Ang4\node_modules@ngtools\webpack\src\plugin.js:212:44)
    at _donePromise.Promise.resolve.then.then.then.then.then (C:\Ravi\Angular\demo\Ang4\node_modules@ngtools\webpack\src\plugin.js:448:24)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue, need two changes:
1. Change peerdependency in library's package.json from 8 to 4.
2. After import this library in the project navigate to "node_modules/library/library_name/metadata.library.json" and change version 4 to 3.